# jquery, bug with my http path

Tags: jquery

i have the following code. I'm not sure where in the code but my hyperlinks aren't working anymore. it just keeps appending to my current url with #. Please forgive me as I am still new to jquery.

thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //   $(function(){
        //      // Tabs
        //      $('#tabs').tabs();
        //   });
     if ($.browser.msie) {
        alert('Website will not be supported in IE, Please use FireFox ');
        window.location.replace('nosupportforie.html');
     }

     // 7 15 2011 EXPERIMENT:
       var tabs,
            tabulation = false,
            initialTab = 'Instructions',
            navSelector = '#tabs .ui-tabs-nav',
            navFilter = function(el) {
                return $(el).attr('href').replace(/^#/, '');
            },
            panelSelector = '#tabs .ui-tabs-panel',
            panelFilter = function() {
                $(panelSelector + ' a').filter(function() {
                    return $(navSelector + ' a[title=' + $(this).attr('title') + ']').size() != 0;
                }).each(function(event) {
                    $(this).attr('href', '#' + $(this).attr('title').replace(/ /g, '_'));
                });
            };

        if ($.address.value() == '') {
            $.address.value(initialTab);
        }

        // Address handler
        $.address.history(false).strict(false).wrap(true).init(function(event) {

            // Adds the ID in a lazy manner to prevent scrolling
            $(panelSelector).attr('id', initialTab);

            // Enables the plugin for all the content links
            $(panelSelector + ' a').address(function() {
                return navFilter(this);
            });

            panelFilter();

            // Tabs setup
            tabs = $('#tabs')
                .tabs({
                    load: function(event, ui) {
                        // Filters the content and applies the plugin if needed
                        $(ui.panel).html($(panelSelector, ui.panel).html());
                        panelFilter();
                    },
                })
                .css('display', 'block');

            // Enables the plugin for all the tabs
            $(navSelector + ' a').click(function(event) {
                tabulation = true;
                $.address.value(navFilter(event.target));
                tabulation = false;
                return false;
            });

        }).change(function(event) {

            var current = $('a[href=#' + event.value + ']:first');

            // Sets the page title
            $.address.title($.address.title().split(' | ')[0] + ' | ' + current.text());

            // Selects the proper tab
            if (!tabulation) {
                tabs.tabs('select', current.attr('href'));
            }
        }).externalChange(function(event) {

            // Select the proper tab
            tabs.tabs('select', $(currentSelector(event.value)).attr('href'));

        }).history(true);
```

....

```
<div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#Instructions" title="Instructions"   >Instructions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Documentations"  >Documents</a></li>    
                <li><a href="#DataExtraction"  >Data Extraction</a></li>
                <li><a href="#FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#UserInfo"   >User Info</a></li>
            </ul>
```

...

```
<script>
        $.get("cgi_scripts/main_userinfo.cgi",function(data){$("#UserInfo").html(data)});
        $.get("cgi_scripts/main_faqpage.cgi",function(data1){$("#FAQ").html(data1)});
        $.get("cgi_scripts/main_intro_page.cgi",function(data2){$("#Instructions").html(data2)});
        $.get("cgi_scripts/main_documentation.cgi",function(data2){$("#Documentations").html(data2)});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I debug the issue to my change statement:

```
                 tabs.tabs('select', $(currentSelector(event.value)).attr('href'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in the jQuery, but in the `href` of your links. You are using hashes, which are appended to the current URL when clicked.

```
<li><a href="#Instructions" title="Instructions"   >Instructions</a></li>
<li><a href="#Documentations"  >Documents</a></li>    
<li><a href="#DataExtraction"  >Data Extraction</a></li>
<li><a href="#FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
<li><a href="#UserInfo"   >User Info</a></li>
```

If you have separate pages with those names, you may need to use something like:

```
<li><a href="/Instructions.html" title="Instructions"   >Instructions</a></li>
```

If you want the user to be redirected to a certain part of the current page when the links are clicked, make sure you have appropriate tags marking the target portions of the page. Example:

```
<a name="Instructions" />
```

Comment: i don't understand, my issues are with my external links on the page

Comment: @Gordon: Which links are the external ones?

Comment: they are somewhere on my other pages say link to go to www.google.com

Comment: my url when click changes to :